# Adding product to website 3 always adds website 1 too

Tags: magento2, product, rest-api, magento-2.2.5

I am in the midst of writing an integration between our ERP system and a new Magento 2 (version 2.2.5) website.

I have never used Magento before, and the setup of the site etc has been managed by a third party.

We have 3 websites, each with one store and one store view; NZ, AU, UK.

I am trying to create a product against our AU website, which is website ID 3.

To do so, I am sending the below request:

```
{
    "product": {
        "sku": "API_TEST-AU",
        "name": "Api Test AU",
        "price": 1337.00,
        "weight": 4.8,
        "visibility": 4,
        "type_id": "simple",
        "attribute_set_id": 4,
        "status": 1,
        "extension_attributes": {
            "website_ids": [
                3
            ],
            "stock_item": {
                "qty": 5,
                "is_in_stock": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I send the request, the response shows that it has also been associated with website ID 1:

[image: Postman request]

Why does this happen and how do I prevent this from happening? I only want the product to be associated with the website IDs I have specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the answer here

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/241402/31830

it is the same issue, The main idea is the endpoint URL, you should use the right endpoint and the default store view for specific website