# How to add a product to a specific website in Magento 2 codebase via api

Tags: magento2, rest-api

My Magento 2.2.4 codebase runs multiple websites, and I am trying to add a product via API to a website with id of "4".

here's the payload of my POST request I tried:

```
{
  "product": {
    "sku": "000012553333",
    "name": "B21232",
    "price": 30.03,
    "status": 1,
    "type_id": "simple",
    "attribute_set_id":4,
    "weight": 1,
    "extension_attributes": {
        "website_ids": [4]
    }
  }
}
```

here's the endpoint:

https://example.com/rest/V1/products

So it adds the product to the website I want AND TO THE DEFAULT website.

So how do I get Magento 2 to add product to a specific website ONLY?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To assign the product to a specific website you cannot use the default endpoint, using this endpoint "https://example.com/rest/V1/products" will assign the product to the default website and the website "4" as well, But if you want to assign the product only to a specific website you have to use this endpoint

https://example.com/rest/**{default store view for website id 4}**/V1/products

please see the attached image

[image]

This is an example endpoint

https://example.com/rest/storev2/V1/products

I Hope this will help you